# Profit function

Tags: calculus

> A firm produces $Q = 2 \sqrt{L}$ units of a commodity when L units of labor are employed. If the price obtained
>   per unit is $ 160$\$, and the price per unit of labor is $  40$\$, what value of $L$ maximizes profits?

Comment: What have you tried? You could start by writing an expression for the profit.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The total amount of money (in and out) is $$M(L) = 160Q - 40L = 320 \sqrt{L} - 40L = 40\sqrt{L}(8 - \sqrt{L})$$

As $L$ is a positive number, let $T = \sqrt{L}$. Now $M(T)=320T - 40 T^2$. You want a maximum, so consider the derivatives
$$M'(T) = 320 - 80T$$
$$M''(T) = -80$$

Then $M'(T)=0$ when $T=4$, and $M''(4)=-80$, which  tells you that $T=4$ is a maximum. In particular then $L=16$ is a maximum.